# Custom Error Page when servlet is not reachable (tomcat8)

Tags: tomcat8

I'm running Tomcat 8.0.21 with java 1.8.0_40

I'm trying to create a costum error page, which should be displayed when I redeploy my application and the servlet is not reachable.

The obvious solution adding:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/ErrorHandler/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

to the `<tomcatDir>/conf/web.xml` won't work here since tomcat always seems to look for the error page in the same servlet. (so e.g. if calling `<url>/idonotexist` he uses the `404.html` located in `ROOT/ErrorHandler/404.html` and not in `ErrorHandler/404.html` as I would have expected) If the webapp is down (stopped via the manager app, or due to maintenance) the error page is blank.
If I remove the lines from the `<tomcatDir>/conf/web.xml` the default tomcat 404 error message is shown though. Is there any possibility to change the default error handling of tomcat?

edit:
ErrorHandler is a deployed webapp with the following web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>Error Application</display-name>
    <description>
    A webapp for error handling
    </description>

    <!-- servlet definition -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ErrorHandler</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <!-- servlet mappings -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ErrorHandler</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

If I call `<tomcatUrl>/ErrorHandler/404.html` in my browser I can view the error page just fine.

Comment: Your error page is there in your undeployed app ? In this case you should have some problem to display it. you may need to create this page in another app, or upload it in the tomcat directory manually

Comment: I've updated my post with some more information for ErrorHandler Servlet